# Creating custom canvas on top of openlayers map

Tags: openlayers

In Leaflet, [I can create](https://github.com/nyurik/leaflet-vega/blob/master/src/VegaLayer.js#L79) a plugin that will create an HTML canvas element as a separate layer. That canvas element will move on mouse drag automatically.

Is there a way I can do the same in OpenLayers 4? E.g. create canvas inside OL's container, and add that canvas to the layers list?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I am looking for something similar, so hopefully we will get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely possible. The https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html shows how to do it. The component you'll want to use is `ol.source.ImageCanvas`. It is configured with a `canvasFunction` that creates a canvas for a given extent, resolution and size.

If, however you want a static canvas to pan/zoom with a map, then `ol.source.ImageStatic` is the component you'll want to use. See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/static-image.html for an example. You can configure it with an Image or Canvas element of a fixed size, extent and resolution, which will be scaled and moved to fix the map's view.

Comment: Is there an example for how to use `ImageStatic` with a canvas element somewhere?

Comment: @Mouagip You can first create a canvas element and put imageData into the context, and use canvas.toDataURL as the url of ImageStatic