# How to place a div on an openlayers map with specific lat/long bounds?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

This can be easily achieved in google maps with an OverlayView, like this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

I want to achieve the same thing in OpenLayers, simply place a div at specific coordinates, and the div scales to fit the specified lat/long bounds.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve the same thing with openlayers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a dynamic div, but you can place images like this via an image layer:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Image-ImageLayer.html

An example is shown here, reprojection might or might not be necessary:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html

If an image is not enough and you need to to display a dynamic div, you could try and render your content into a `canvas`-element and create an image from there... but this solution does not scale well (pun intended).

Comment: Is there an example of using a canvas element? I've spent a long time researching this and I'm very surprised there isn't a simple way to just pin an element to specific coordinates.

Comment: Pinning an element to a specific coordinate is no issue at all, this can easily be done with an overlay:
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Overlay-Overlay.html
but these overlays are not meant to fit specified lat/long bounds, but rather display information. Most of the time, you want an overlay like that. Image layers are meant to overlay geographic data, like in the google-maps example you postet

Comment: thank you for the follow up, the problem I'm having is that the overlay needs to fit specific lat/long bounds, but the overlay is *not* an image. It's a canvas element containing editable indoor maps for specific locations, so it needs to scale correctly and stay within the specified bounds. I was able to easily achieve this in google maps with a custom OverlayView. Do you have any suggestions for how to create an overlay that fits specific lat/long bounds that is not an image? Preferably, it would be a div like in the Google maps example I posted in the op.

Comment: ok i understand, maybe have a quick look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182592/5801610
it also has a linked example to a map that uses an svg as an overlay, similar to your usecase

Comment: You can pass a canvas element to ol/source/ImageStatic as a dataURL.